# Microsoft TTS SaveToWaveFileAsync function not working

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, text-to-speech

I am developing a mobile text to speech application using Xamarin Forms. The [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp) worked so far and synthesised my text but saving the result to a file does not seem to work. This is the code from the class which synthesised:

```
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("6e4a67f034a545e0833179044dd6d172", "westeurope");
        var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config);
        var result = await synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(xmlFirstPart + voice + xmlSecondPart + synthesisText + xmlThirdPart).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var stream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
      
        string file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "SpeechSynthesis.wav");
        await stream.SaveToWaveFileAsync(file);
```

It gives no error but once I call it from another class with this code:

```
ISimpleAudioPlayer player = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
player.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "SpeechSynthesis.wav"));
```

It gives the following error:

> Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: '/data/user/0/com.companyname.mobileapp/files/SpeechSynthesis.wav'

If anybody knows what may be a possible cause for this error, it would be of much help to me. Thank you.

Comment: For text to speech function you could use Xamarin.Essentials . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/text-to-speech

Answer (score 0):

The usage looks fine but the path you are using seems to be wrong: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "SpeechSynthesis.wav"`.

Try giving `"path/to/write/file.wav"` for instance, it shall work.

*Alternatively*, you can use below code for saving to .wav:

```
using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput("path/to/write/file.wav");
```

Comment: Sadly this does not solve the problem - the same error persists. I tested the file path with File.exists . It returns true but whenever I try to use the player.Load function it says that no such file exists. I am confused because these two contradict each other.

Comment: Can you try the code explained here?: https://codexamarin.blogspot.com/2019/01/play-audio-in-xamarin-forms-using.html

Comment: Also, which path are you giving in `player.Load`? Is it same as `SaveToWaveFileAsync`'s path?

Comment: I am using the same path. The Player.Load does not return an error but rather just freezes.

Comment: Yep. It works. But the wav file must be in the resources folder. The file I am trying to play is created in run-time.

Comment: Got it. Then, try to integrate your forst path with this working code. It should work because the logic remains same. If you want further assistance on debugging, let me know